# ASP.Net Security Authorization Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I want to make Security authorization management model

that can manage all roles and users rights on the system .

manage role operation

role "Manager" => right "Edit All User Information"

role "HR" => right "View and Edit Employe"

and so on...

how can i do that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Enterprise Library Security Application Block. It may just be what you wanted

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664559(v=PandP.50).aspx

Comment: but i didnt understand what is the differant between this and the normar asp.net membership provider

Comment: It gives you more flexibility to use other providers beyond just the standard ASP.NET membership database and also another layer of framework that you can then easily apply the security authorization against resources access and configuring through config file as well. Either search of google on how others are using it. This site has a good summary on step with some directional links http://www.education.vic.gov.au/devreskit/appdev/Application%20Blocks/Security/security-standards-details.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that with the provider model using Membership and Roles. Take a look at this set of articles for a heads up on how to use that:

[Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)